# Laptop won't connect to Wi-Fi router

Tags: wireless, networking, laptop, router

I have Ubuntu in one of the laptops I own.

Since yesterday, and for no apparent reason, it is not able to connect anymore to my Wi-Fi router (I tried to *forget* the network and disabled security, still not connecting).

The confusing thing is that:

- The laptop is able to connect to other Wi-Fis.
- My other devices are able to connect to my router's Wi-Fi.

It is like the router and the laptop got mad with each other.

So I don't really know how to interpret this. Any idea?

Comment: Does the router use WPA or WPA2? These two security methods are quite annoying.

Comment: WPA2, but I even disabled the security of the WIFI just to try, and amazingly it still refuses to connect, whereas the rest of the devices do...... and the laptop connects to other networks... i don't know what to think... I also restarted the router, I still didn't reset it.

Comment: Did you disable security on both the router and the laptop?

Comment: Well, i disabled the security on the router and then deleted the network on the laptop and try to connect to the new free WIFI as if it was an unknown one, and it was not able. My other laptop and phone were able to connect to the router...

Comment: What is the SSID? Ubuntu might not like some SSID's.

Comment: "dlink" The thing is that it was connecting without problems until yesterday... when suddenly it wouldn't connect anymore, i didn't do any change, i just turned it on and it was not connecting, then i checked that other devices were able, and that the computer was connecting to other Wifis also, i am totally lost with this...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4570/discussion-between-obsessivefoss-and-edutesoy)